# Epson WF-2520 Printer on Network (Ethernet-Connected)-- iScan

Tags: networking, scanner, epson

This specific printer does print normally both in elemntary OS and Lubuntu. But the Image Scan! for Linux does not work
`iScan:Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner's status.`

I am new here, trying to set my equipment.

Comment: Did you install network-plugin?

Comment: Yes, of course. All the necessary .deb files.

Comment: Did you set the scanner IP in config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add IP address of your scanner to `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf`.

In this format, e.g.

```
net 192.168.1.100
```